# HTML/CSS <div> of links stuck at top of screen when programmed to be at bottom

Tags: html, css

I have a div of links that is stuck at the middle of the page. It's like a "press to go to top of page" set of links that is supposed to be belong at the bottom(where I have it in HTML). I believe the problem is that I have an absolute div with 3 divs relative within it, and this has somehow pushed the links that are supposed to belong at the bottom into the "middle" of the absolute div. I just can't seem to get the set of links to sit pretty at the problem after the absolute div with 3 divs in it. Can anyone help me? I've been trying to figure this out all day. Thanks.
Richard

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#whole {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

#1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

#2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href=example1.css>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hey</h1>
  <div id=whole>
    <div id=1>Hi </div>
    <br>
    <div id=2>Hey</div>
  </div>
  <div>Links</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Richard please post some code so we can take a look

Comment: Edit your question and include your code.

Comment: can you share the screenshot

Comment: There you go, I've added everything I could think of.

Comment: @RichardDuong You are supposed to provide the code to recreate the problem. Just giving us the CSS won't help much. Add a snippet so we can help better

Comment: it's so complicated to post code on here... but I have just figured it out... thanks all.

Comment: It's not complicated. Paste the code, select it, press Ctrl+K. Or use the stackSnippet editor (press the button marked `<>`). Anyway, if you want the div to be positioned absolutely at the bottom, use the `bottom` property.

Comment: I've added a photo.

Comment: I've finally figured it out and added the code, sorry guys...if anyone can help at this point, it would be greatly appreciated. I just want the Links portion to sit at the bottom without have to use "margin-top:-1800px" or "-250%" because depending on the size of the screen, it is always moving around. Thanks a bunch all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position:fixed` on links div like this

```
.links{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

or move links div inside #whole and use `position:absolute`,

```
<div id="whole">
        <div id="1">Hi </div>
        <br>
        <div id="2">Hey</div>
      <div class="links">Links</div>
</div>

.links{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Here is example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6vk8Ld8p/)

Comment: Thanks Sasith, but what I specifically wanted was that it would stay outside the absolute div, on the bottom, and stay put. I'm aware of the methods that you posted but it was not what I was looking for. At this point, I just want to know if it's possible. Thanks.